# R merge a aggregate quarterly data.table to a bilateral yearly data.table while expanding the quarterly dimension for each i

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to merge two `data.tables`. One is yearly and bilateral such as:

```
library(data.table)
bilateral <- data.table(country=c("AT","AT","DE","DE"),
             counterparty=c("DE","FR","AT","FR"),
             time=c("2001Q1"),
             bilateral_value=rnorm(4))
bilateral[,countrypair:=paste(country,counterparty,sep="_")]
```

the other is aggregated and quarterly, such as:

```
quarterly <- data.table(country=c(rep("DE",4),rep("AT",4)),
                    time=c(rep(c("2001Q1","2001Q2","2001Q3","2001Q4"),2)),
                    aggregate_value=rnorm(8))
```

I want to merge by year and by time (yearquarter) which works of course:

```
Data <- merge(bilateral, quarterly,by=c("country","time"),all=T)
```

but I would like to fill up the quarters (with `NA's` for countrypair but `aggregate_value` corresponding to `country`), so I want to duplicate the values in the quarterly dataset for every bilateral pair based on `country`. I think this should be possible directly in `merge.data.table` but I can't figure out how.

I am aiming for:

```
goal <- data.table(country=c(rep("DE",8),rep("AT",8)),
                   counterparty=c("AT",NA,NA,NA,"FR",NA,NA,NA,"DE",NA,NA,NA,
                                  "FR",NA,NA,NA),
                   time=c(rep(c("2001Q1","2001Q2","2001Q3","2001Q4"),4)),
                   bilateral_value=c(Data[1,bilateral_value],NA,NA,NA,
                                     Data[2,bilateral_value],NA,NA,NA,
                                     Data[6,bilateral_value],NA,NA,NA,
                                     Data[7,bilateral_value],NA,NA,NA),
                   countrypair=c("AT_DE",NA,NA,NA,"AT_FR",NA,NA,NA,"DE_AT",NA,NA,NA,
                                 "DE_FR",NA,NA,NA),
                   aggregate_value=c(rep(Data[2:5,aggregate_value],2),
                                     rep(Data[7:10,aggregate_value],2)))
```

Comment: "aggregate_value corresponding to country" -- This does not hold in your `goal` data set unless I'm looking at it wrong. Also, you seem to use countries FR and Fr... maybe be more careful and/or simplify your example.

Comment: Fr edited, thatnks! The aggregated data repeats for every counterparty within a country, thats fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I think this returns the same output as goal. It includes your code and then uses a cross join (`CJ`) afterward to expand to the desired level:

```
# set key for cross join
setkey(Data, country, counterparty, time)
temp <- Data[CJ(unique(country), 
         unique(counterparty), unique(time))][country != counterparty & !is.na(counterparty)]
```

As @Frank pointed out, this can be shortened (and may be more efficient) using the unique argument in `CJ`:

```
    temp <- Data[CJ(country, counterparty, time, unique=T)
                 ][country != counterparty & !is.na(counterparty)]
```

Finally, the aggregate value variable is filled in using a left join onto quarterly:

```
# remove partially filled agg_value column
temp[, aggregate_value := NULL]
# join on full aggregate value column
temp[quarterly, on=c("country", "time")]
```

Comment: thats perfect, thanks! I didnt know about crossjoin, thats exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Frank. I was wondering what that argument was doing there.